# glmer VS JAGS: different results in intercept-only hierarchical model

Tags: r, glm, hierarchical, jags

## JAGS

I have an intercept-only logistic model in JAGS, defined as follows:

```
model{
for(i in 1:Ny){
    y[i] ~ dbern(mu[s[i]])
}
for(j in 1:Ns){
    mu[j] <- ilogit(b0[j])
    b0[j] ~ dnorm(0, sigma)
}

sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
}
```

When I plot the posterior distribution of `b0` collapsing across all subjects (i.e., all `b0[j]`), my 95% HDI includes `0`: `-0.55 to 2.13`. The Effective Sample Size is way above 10,000 for every `b0` (around 18,000 on average). Diagnostics look good.

## `glmer()`

Now, this is the equivalent `glmer()` model:

```
glmer(response ~ 1 + (1|subject), data = myData, family = "binomial")
```

The result of this model, however, is as follows:

```
Random effects:
Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
speaker (Intercept) 0.3317   0.576   
Number of obs: 1544, groups:  subject, 27

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.7401     0.1247   5.935 2.94e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So here it says my estimate is significantly **above** `0`.

## What the data look like

Here are the proportions of `0s` and `1s` by subject. You can see that, for the vast majority of subjects, the proportion of `1` is above 50%.

**Any ideas why JAGS and `glmer()` are so different here?**

```
      0    1
1  0.47 0.53
2  0.36 0.64
3  0.29 0.71
4  0.42 0.58
5  0.12 0.88
6  0.22 0.78
7  0.54 0.46
8  0.39 0.61
9  0.30 0.70
10 0.32 0.68
11 0.36 0.64
12 0.66 0.34
13 0.38 0.62
14 0.49 0.51
15 0.35 0.65
16 0.32 0.68
17 0.12 0.88
18 0.45 0.55
19 0.36 0.64
20 0.36 0.64
21 0.28 0.72
22 0.40 0.60
23 0.41 0.59
24 0.19 0.81
25 0.27 0.73
26 0.08 0.92
27 0.12 0.88
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to include a mean value, so your intercept parameter is fixed to zero.  Something like this should work:

```
model{
for(i in 1:Ny){
    y[i] ~ dbern(mu[s[i]])
}
for(j in 1:Ns){
    mu[j] <- ilogit(b0[j])
    b0[j] ~ dnorm(mu0, sigma)
}
mu0 ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
}
```

Now the posterior density of `mu0` should match the sampling distribution of the intercept parameter from `glmer` reasonably well.

Alternatively, if you use `response ~ -1 + (1|subject)` as your `glmer` formula, you should get results that match your current JAGS model.

Comment: Thanks! But the HDI of the JAGS model still includes 0. So in a way these two models are giving me different decisions regarding the possible effect (and whether it's different from 0). Is that expected, or are these two models not equivalent...?

Comment: are you looking at the posterior density of `mu0` ?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. No, I wasn't. I am now, and it does match what I'd expect from the glm() model. Thanks a lot—I'm totally new to JAGS and the transition isn't that smooth.

Comment: depending on what you're doing, you might be interested in the `brms` and/or `rstanarm` packages

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.

Comment: One more question regarding the model above, if you don't mind: will this model cause shrinkage? Is shrinkage a natural consequence of this type of hierarchical structure, or do I need to explicitly add code to make the individual-level parameters shrink towards the group-level parameters?

Comment: Yes (shrinkage), yes (natural), no (explicit machinery to cause shrinkage)

Comment: Great. Thanks again.